# Flickering issue when overlaying a div on hover of another div

Tags: html, css

Apologies if the title is confusing. Basically I've got a div which, on hover, activates a second div to `display:block`, displaying it above the underlying div. Works well except for the flickering I experience when moving the cursor over the second div.

Another minor issue is that the second div disappears for a fraction of a second when it's clicked.

Check this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uB82S/1/

Comment: Just so you know, there are a couple of syntax errors.. you forgot a semi-colon, and a close tag in the CSS. As for the problem itself, use visibility rather than `display:none` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: Are the images content or could they just be background images? There are a number of ways this rollover effect could be achieved.

Comment: It's worth noting that the issue seems to be related to the targeting of sibling elements. ie the original question attempts to display .main-img when its sibling, .feature-product, is hovered over. All of the answers to date (Jack, It San, Huangism) resolve this in one way or another by changing the hovered element to be the displayed element's parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**

### [View this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uB82S/5/)

**

Change your HTML to be:

```
<div class="product-main">

   <div id="img-container" class="img-container">

   <div class="feature-product-img" id="feature-product-img" style="display: block;">
      <a href="http://www.spinnakerextreme.com/2012-tt-isle-of-man-official-review-blu-ray-and-dvd.html" title="2012 TT Isle of Man Official Review Blu Ray and DVD">
           <img class="product-img" src="http://www.spinnakerextreme.com/media/catalog/product/p/r/product_2_bg.png" alt="2012 TT Isle of Man Official Review Blu Ray and DVD" />
      </a>
      ****move this inside the feature-product div****
     <div class="main-img" id="main-img">
        <a href="http://www.spinnakerextreme.com/2012-tt-isle-of-man-official-review-blu-ray-and-dvd.html" title="2012 TT Isle of Man Official Review Blu Ray and DVD">
            <img src="http://www.spinnakerextreme.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/t/tt_man_review_1.png" height="184" id="main-image-img"/>
        </a>
     </div>
     ************
 </div>
</div>
<div class="product-description">
  <a href="http://www.spinnakerextreme.com/2012-tt-isle-of-man-official-review-blu-ray-and-dvd.html" title="2012 TT Isle of Man Official Review Blu Ray and DVD">
      2012 TT Isle of Man Official Review Blu Ray and DVD
   </a>
</div>
```

Change css to:

```
.feature-product-img:hover > .main-img{
 display:block;
}

.feature-product-img .main-img:active {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the hover on the product container instead. This way it provides a more stable way for the main image to show

http://jsfiddle.net/uB82S/9/

```
.product-main {
    display: inline-block;
}
.product-main:hover .main-img{
    display:block;
}

.main-img:active {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the correct selector. See http://jsfiddle.net/uB82S/7/

```
/*
.feature-product-img:hover + .main-img {
    display:block;
}
.feature-product-img + .main-img:active {
    display:block;
}
* replace with below ..
*/
#img-container:hover div#main-img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```